# Remove brakets and string and SPACE following

Tags: jquery, string, replace, space

I have a variable string like such:  [Text that changes]:SPACE:  where the :SPACE: is actually a normal space.  I need to remove the brackets and everything inside, plus the space following.

I have this:

```
      //<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
function stripParenthesis( node ) {
    if(node.length) {
        node.contents().each(function(index, child) {
            if( child.nodeType === 3 ) {
                child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
            }
            else {
                stripParenthesis( $(child) );
            }
        });
    }
}

stripParenthesis( $('div#brackets') );   });  //]]>
```

This manages to remove the brackets and everything inside.  But what about the space following?  I don't know how to adjust the following to make it include both the closing bracket and the space following...

```
.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '')
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.  Also, this function will hopefully work even if at some point there is no bracket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enter code here`Just need to add the \s (whitespace char) at the end.

```
.replace(/\[.*?\]\s/g, '')
```

test it out here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

**EDIT** -- Complete Code:

```
//<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
function stripParenthesis( node ) {
    if(node.length) {
        node.contents().each(function(index, child) {
            if( child.nodeType === 3 ) {
                child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(/\[.*?\]\s/g, '');
            }
            else {
                stripParenthesis( $(child) );
            }
        });
    }
}

stripParenthesis( $('div#brackets') );   });  //]]>
```

Comment: I should mention that you just need the regex string for testing on the gskinner.com/RegExr/ as it checks regex without any other programming code needed. There are also some helpful examples there.

Comment: I knew I was close.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I used the following because the original code sometimes had two or more spaces that the browser interpreted as one: .replace(/\[.*?\] +/g, '')

Comment: That works too. You could have also done: .replace(/\[.*?/\]\s{0,1}/g,''); (or just use {1} if you are sure it's 1 and only 1 space you are looking for)

Answer (score 1):

This should work I believe

```
child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(/\[.*?\]\s/g, '');
```

Comment: we submitted within 28 seconds of each other. Looks like we both had the same idea. :) You beat me to the punch though, nicely done.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Ended up using the following because sometimes the white space was two or more blanks in the original code:   .replace(/\[.*?\] +/g, '')